# Why this list can't be stored as element in data frame?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, element

I ran a `randomforest` model and tried to store the model as an element in a data frame. I usually wrap things up with `list()` and store it as an element, but here it seems I need two layers `list(list())`. Can somebody explian why, and tell me if `list(list())` is a good way to fix this?

```
library(randomForest)

data1 = data.frame(A = sample.int(100, size = 100))
data1$B = data1$A
data1$C = data1$A
data1$D = data1$A

report = data.frame(ntree = 500, mtry = 1:3, model = NA)

for ( i_row in 1:nrow(report)){

        ntree = report[i_row, 'ntree']
        mtry = report[i_row, 'mtry']

        rf = randomForest( D ~ ., data = data1, importance = T, ntree = ntree, mtry = mtry)

        report[i_row, 'model'] = rf  # not work
        report[i_row, 'model'] = list(rf)  # not work
        report[i_row, 'model'] = list(list(rf))  # works
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can store it as an attribute instead? `attr(report, "model") <- rf`? Or make `report` a `list` instead of a `data.frame`...?

Comment: Thanks @AnandaMahto  I'm not super familiar with attr - can we have multiple indexed attr? See update in OP please.

Comment: Based on your update, you really should just be using a `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data Frames are internally lists and if you consider `str(rf)` you see that the randomForest-model is internally also represented as a list. But the attributes have different dimensions, so `rf` can't be transformed to a `data.frame`

R tries the best for you to convert a list or a list of lists in some reasonable way to a data.frame. Consider

```
a <- data.frame(x=c(1,2),y=c(1,2))
```

In the assignment

```
a[2,] <- list(x=3, y=3)
```

the right hand list is interpreted as a row assigned to the second row of `a`.

The assignment `a[2,] <- list(list(x=3, y=3))` fails because the right hand side cannot be interpreted as a row, but it can be coerced to a column:

```
a[,1] <- list(list(x=3, y=3))
```

This results in

```
  x y
1 3 1
2 3 2
```

Finally, the `list(list(...))` "trick" in this case is:

```
a[2,] <- list(list(list(x=3, y=3)))
> a
     x    y
1    1    1
2 3, 3 3, 3
```

Now R gave it up to coerce the right hand side object into rows and columns and accepted it as a wrapped list of lists. This is more or less the same what you did.

So at least it works reproducible. But if this is a good idea? I would deny it.

Dataframes are intended for tabular data, not for wrapping complex objects into lists of lists.

Comment: thanks @PatrickRoocks. So what would be a neat R way to write this? Use an indexed list to store all models?

Comment: Yes, I would recommend a list containing all the randomForest model objects.

Comment: thanks @PatrickRoocks. I do realize something to support your idea. When the data frame contains something weird, you click it and the table sometimes doesn't show up (in Rstudio), (Sometimes it does and I haven't tested what specifically cause the table not shown....)